# WinRT does not report an exception when running in a non-UI thread

Tags: multithreading, windows-runtime

In a thread I catch ThreadCanceledException, but not others, in hope to see errors, if any. However, when a thread starts and the code has an error, it produces messages

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in ...
The thread ... has exited with code 259 (0x103)
```

and gracefully quits without showing the actual exception. The error can be identified only if I run the code in UI thread.

Is there a way to get the actual exception to be reported within a thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trace those exceptions by using the [`TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event:

```
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Unobserved exception: {0}", eventArgs.Exception);
};
```

Note that this event will not be triggered immediately, but after the faulty task has been collected by the garbage collector. That's because the code that created the task is the one supposed to observe the exception (for instance by calling `task.Wait()` or `task.Result`, or by awaiting it). The event will be triggered only once the runtime is certain that nobody else can observe the exception.